# Differentiation in functional equations (calculus of variations)

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations

I am studying calculus of variations, and I see functions of this sort quite a bit:
$$F(x,y,\dot{y})$$
Why is $\dot{y}$ mentioned in these functions? Is it incomplete to simply state that $F(x,y,\frac{dy}{dx})$ is equivalent to some $G(x,y)$?

Also, let's say I introduce a variable $\bar{y}$, such that
$$\bar{y}(x) = y(x) + \epsilon \eta (x)$$ for some $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\eta$ is some arbitrary function of $x$
And decide to differentiate $F(x,\bar{y},\frac{d\bar{y}}{dx})$ wrt $\epsilon$.
I expected something like this from the chain rule:
$$\frac{dF}{d\epsilon} = \frac{dF}{dx} \frac{dx}{d\epsilon} + \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}} \frac{d\bar{y}}{dx} \frac{dx}{d\epsilon} + \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}'} \frac{d\bar{y}'}{dx} \frac{dx}{d\epsilon}$$
However, from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFqp2lCEvwM&list=PLdgVBOaXkb9CD8igcUr9Fmn5WXLpE8ZE_&index=2 at 4:46, you can see that
$$\frac{dF}{d\epsilon} =  \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}} \frac{d\bar{y}}{d\epsilon} + \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}'} \frac{d\bar{y}'}{d\epsilon}$$.

Of course, in the video they are deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation, so $x$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ and gets cancelled, but the other terms survive.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If $x$ were dependent on $\epsilon$ then you would get that first chain rule expansion, but $x$ doesn't depend on $\epsilon.$

Comment: The reason for $F(x, y(x), \dot{y}(x))$ is primarily to explicitly show that the expression for $F$ may contain both $x,$ $y(x)$ and $\dot{y}(x).$ An example:
$$F(x, y(x), \dot{y}(x)) = \frac12 \dot{y}(x)^2 - \frac12 x^2 y(x)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Why is $\dot{y}$ is mentioned in these functions? Is it incomplete to simply state that $F\left(x,y,\frac{dy}{dx} \right)$ is equivalent to some $G(x,y)$?*

$F(x,y,\dot{y})$ is a function of $3$ variables. These variables are **independent**. We use this function as a *functional* that depends on variable $x$, function $y$ and its first derivative. Notation can be a little bit misleading (we just denote the third variable as $\dot{y}$). So it is not equivalent to some function $G(x,y)$, because we're considering arguments $y$ and $\dot{y}$ as independent (even though eventually third argument $\dot{y}$ appears to be first derivative of $y$).

Regarding your second questing, as already has been pointed in comments, $x$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$, so applying chain rule you get
$$
\frac{dF}{d\epsilon} =  \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}} \frac{d\bar{y}}{d\epsilon} + \frac{dF}{d\bar{y}'} \frac{d\bar{y}'}{d\epsilon}.
$$

Comment: "because we're considering ...as independent". But why we do so? As a matter of fact they are not independent.